# Javascript - Pause - Free Memory

Tags: javascript

Using the below it refreshes the screen using the dataRefreshButton function based else where in the code.

However I am finding Firefox, Chrome and IE do not have the chance to free up memory. So I am trying to pause the refresh every so often, to try to give the browser the chance to catch. This does not seem to pause like I would expect, whether or not when it does, it will work fine in terms allowing memory to be freed.

So question is, what is the best way to stop the refresh (setInterval) and then allow it to resume after approx ten seconds?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function getdata(){

        counter++;
        if(counter==20) {

           clearInterval(reset, 10000);


        }
        //window.alert(counter);
       document.getElementById('dataRefreshButton').click();

    }


    function reset() {


            intGetData = setInterval(getdata, 4000);
            counter=0;


    }

    var intGetData;
    var counter = 0;

    function sel1(){
        var ref = document.getElementById('AutoRefresh').checked;


        if(ref == true) {


            intGetData = setInterval(getdata, 4000);


  window.alert("Auto refresh on");
        }

        else{
            clearInterval(intGetData);  
         //   window.alert("Auto refresh off");   

        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I don't see what you mean by "*do not have the change to free up memory*". And 4s is a long enough time to do GC… Btw, you did forgot to include the buttons markup

Comment: Sorry "chance". I would have thought 4s is enough as well. I will include the buttons markup too.